# How to create a jarfile based on a shell script in bash

Tags: bash

I already have a shell script that can uninstall and install an app from brew in bash, but I kinda want to make it a little easier to run.  Basically, what I'm trying to do is create a jarfile that can run the shell script that contains my commands.  Is there a way to do this (easily package a shell script in a jarfile)?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not sure how anything could be easier to run than a shell script, especially a jar file.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to create a jarfile that runs a shell script that (un)installs a homebrew-installed app? Why not just alias `brew (un)install yourpackage` to something short? Seems like an XY problem.

Comment: It's easier for me just to use an icon-related shortcut that I can easily place in Downloads.  Anyway, is this even possible?